Can bus data reading error with PCAN Canable Adapter
I am working on project. The idea is to read can bus vehicle data and visualize it on screen.
The Rasperry Pi 4 was chosen as platform, python and its GUI Kivy, python can library.
the can reader is Pcan Canable adapter.
on PC with windows everything works perfectly, but switching to the RPI4 I have faced difficulties.
App is working for some period of time, is depicting data as it supposed to be but some moment after it is going down with error:
File "/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/can/notifier.py", line 124, in _rx_thread
if msg := bus.recv(self.timeout):
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/can/bus.py", line 126, in recv
msg, already_filtered = self._recv_internal(timeout=time_left)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/can/interfaces/pcan/pcan.py", line 558, in _recv_internal
raise PcanCanOperationError(self._get_formatted_error(result))
can.interfaces.pcan.pcan.PcanCanOperationError: The CAN controller was read too late
the chank of my code is here:
import can
** and so on **

''' other classes over here '''


class Can_data(can.Listener):
    print("reading can messages")

    def on_message_received(self, msg):
        # print(f"data: {msg}")
        if msg.arbitration_id == 0x316 and msg is not None:
            Dash_Board.rpm = msg.data[3] * 7000 / 110
            Dash_Board.arrow_rpm = Dash_Board.rpm
            print("rpm: ", Dash_Board.rpm)
            Dash_Board.rpm = round(Dash_Board.rpm / 50) * 50

        elif msg.arbitration_id == 0x1F1 and msg is not None:
            Dash_Board.speed = int(msg.data[4] * 220 / 110)
            Dash_Board.arrow_speed = Dash_Board.speed * 260 / 220
            print("t: ", Dash_Board.speed)
            # uncoment to filter data
        elif msg.arbitration_id == 0x0A0 and msg is not None:
            Dash_Board.t = msg.data[1] - 40
            print("t: ", Dash_Board.t)
        elif msg.arbitration_id == 0x0A1 and msg is not None:
            Dash_Board.boost = msg.data[4]
            print("boost: ", Dash_Board.boost)
        elif msg.arbitration_id == 0x0350 and msg is not None:
            Dash_Board.fuel = msg.data[3] * 0.75
            print("tank: ", Dash_Board.fuel)
        else:
            print("no message recieved")

    def stop(self):
        print("stoped")


class Read_bus_data():

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        print("reading bus data")

        self.filter = [
            {"can_id": 0x316, "can_mask": 0x7FF, "extended": False},
            {"can_id": 0x1F1, "can_mask": 0x7FF, "extended": False},
            {"can_id": 0x0A0, "can_mask": 0x7FF, "extended": False},
            {"can_id": 0x0A1, "can_mask": 0x7FF, "extended": False},
            {"can_id": 0x350, "can_mask": 0x7FF, "extended": False}
        ]

        self.bus = None
        self.notifier = None

        self.start_bus()

    def start_bus(self):
        try:
            self.bus = can.Bus(interface='pcan', channel='PCAN_USBBUS1', can_filters=self.filter, timeout=2)

            listen = Can_data()
            self.notifier = can.Notifier(self.bus, [listen], timeout=2)

            
            # with self.bus as bus:
            # msg = self.bus.recv(0.1)
            # for msg in bus:
            # if msg.arbitration_id == 0x316 and msg is not None:
            # Dash_Board.rpm = msg.data[3]*7000/110
            # Dash_Board.arrow_rpm = Dash_Board.rpm
            # print("rpm: ", Dash_Board.rpm)
            # Dash_Board.rpm = round(Dash_Board.rpm/50)*50

            # elif msg.arbitration_id == 0x1F1 and msg is not None:
            # Dash_Board.speed = int(msg.data[4]*220/110)
            # Dash_Board.arrow_speed = Dash_Board.speed*260/220
            # print("t: ", Dash_Board.speed)
            # # #uncoment to filter data
            # if msg.arbitration_id == 0x0A0 and msg is not None:
            # Dash_Board.t = msg.data[1] - 40
            # print("t: ", Dash_Board.t)
            # elif msg.arbitration_id == 0x0A1 and msg is not None:
            # Dash_Board.boost = msg.data[4]
            # print("boost: ", Dash_Board.boost)
            # elif msg.arbitration_id == 0x0350 and msg is not None:
            # Dash_Board.fuel = msg.data[3]*0.75
            # print("tank: ", Dash_Board.fuel)
            # else:
            # print("no message recieved")


        except Exception as e:
            print("error", e)
            # self.cleanup()




class Dashboard_project(MDApp):


    def build(self):

        sm = MDScreenManager()

        sm.add_widget(Classic_style_dash_board())
        sm.add_widget(Sport_style_dash_board())
        sm.add_widget(Engine())

        Read_bus_data()

        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Dashboard_project().run()


My App works some period of time, after paying attention to Messages' traces, it is visible as it gets some delay and after can bus gets that error above
I have tried a lot of things.

to use a PCANBasic library from PEAK system. It works, but very slowly.
updating drivers
updating OS and optimize hardware
provide with more efficient power supply
check Can reader with Arduino+MCP2515 can messenger emulator as sender and Pcan canable reader, python-can library's can viewer - everything works without any doubts
use threading.queue to read off data and pass it in other class put result is that same
Generally nothing helps and I do not see any consistent pattern, it can works for either for 10 sec or 10 min. That's why first thing which I suspected was issues with wire and power reliability.
But whatever I tried, nothing was helping.
Maybe here I will get some new ideas which would give a second breathe.
thank you in advance


You get that error, when the receive queue of your CAN controller is overflowing. I.e. your application is not reading the messages fast enough. First guess is that you should not update your UI in the Listener-callback. You say that you tried to decouple that using threading. How did that code look like?

basically, the issue is solved.
I have analyzed my code, cracked it to several chunks, embed timer and noticed a delay in some of them.
Observing it in details I put attention to that, I had assigned a couple of Clock.schedule_interval processes with my widgets, I really slowed down my App.
Can library had got an error because it had a lot of not treated messages in buffer.
Now it works even without of queue.Queue().

I have a canable USB V2.0 nano. It sees CAN messages via the can0 interface but not all of them. Messages with high bits set in the extended identifier seem to be ignored or filtered out. My CANFD modules using STM32G431 and Microchip MCP2515 and PIC18 can
all see these messages, but not the CANABLE USB stick!
From a linux MCP2515 rpi buildroot linux:
# ./can_rx | egrep "F1DF"
10:27:08.995 8F1DF000 7 bytes : 00 0d 63 2d 2a 00 34   U2U class=0(READ), UNKNOWN13 = 0.000000
10:27:09.249 8F1DF001 7 bytes : 00 11 9b 2d 2a 00 34   UNKNOWN
10:27:09.489 8F1DF000 7 bytes : 00 0d 63 2d 2a 00 34   U2U class=0(READ), UNKNOWN13 = 0.000000
10:27:09.744 8F1DF001 7 bytes : 00 11 86 2d 2a 00 34   UNKNOWN
10:27:09.983 8F1DF000 7 bytes : 00 0d 63 2d 2a 00 34   U2U class=0(READ), UNKNOWN13 = 0.000000
10:27:10.237 8F1DF001 7 bytes : 00 11 6e 2d 2a 00 34   UNKNOWN

But the same can bus on the CANABLE does not see these
0x0F1DF000 messages.
$ candump can0 | more
  can0  00001038   [8]  30 1E 00 5C 00 0A 04 04
  can0  000AA010   [8]  0D 86 00 00 00 00 00 00
  can0  00011010   [8]  04 25 00 00 00 00 C0 7F
  can0  00001000   [8]  84 25 00 00 20 00 00 00
  can0  00011010   [8]  04 26 00 00 00 00 C0 7F
  can0  00011010   [8]  04 23 00 00 00 00 C0 7F
  can0  00001000   [8]  84 26 00 00 20 00 00 00
  can0  00011010   [8]  04 27 00 00 00 00 C0 7F
  can0  00011010   [8]  04 0C 00 00 00 00 C0 7F
  can0  00001000   [8]  84 27 00 00 11 00 80 3F
  can0  00001000   [8]  84 0C 00 00 08 44 1C 46
  can0  0000000E   [5]  FF 02 41 1C 00
  can0  0000A7E5   [8]  EF 01 13 24 54 00 20 01
  can0  00011010   [8]  04 07 00 00 00 00 C0 7F
  can0  00011010   [8]  04 08 00 00 00 00 C0 7F
  can0  00011010   [8]  04 0F 00 00 00 00 C0 7F
  can0  00011010   [8]  04 0D 00 00 00 00 C0 7F
  can0  00001000   [8]  84 0D 00 00 00 00 00 00
  can0  00011010   [8]  04 16 00 00 00 00 C0 7F
  can0  00011010   [8]  04 0E 00 00 00 00 C0 7F
  can0  0000100E   [5]  FF 02 0B 1C 00
  can0  000AA010   [8]  0D 87 00 00 00 00 00 00
  can0  00011010   [8]  04 10 00 00 00 00 C0 7F
  can0  000017E4   [8]  00 29 00 00 00 00 20 30
  can0  0000103A   [7]  31 FF F5 FF E6 53 B2
  can0  00001038   [8]  31 1E 00 5C 00 0B 04 04
  can0  00011010   [8]  04 14 00 00 00 00 C0 7F

